# Is WebGL part of the Html5 specification

Tags: webgl

So I know (think?) WebGL depends on the  element of html5, but is it part of the html5 spec itself?

I used to think they were two different things, much like CSS3 and html5. But then I saw it as one of the criteria tested in http://html5test.com/.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WebGL is not part of HTML 5 specification.But this  belongs to khronos group.More info can be had from this link:

```
www.khronos.org/webgl
```

Comment: Can you point to some page that claims what is officially HTML5?

Answer (score 6):

Let's start by identifying what HTML 5 is.  The W3C has a spec with a [history section](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/introduction.html#history-1) that details how the different HTML version numbers came about.

The WHATWG, for its part, considers HTML to be a "Living Standard", free of version numbers, but still [includes HTML5 in its description](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#is-this-html5?) of that standard.

WebGL itself is not part of either of the above specifications directly, although you'll find a reference to it if you search the WHATWG document above.  So officially, no, not part of HTML5.  WebGL does, as you mention, depend on the `<canvas>` element from HTML5.

In practice, however, I've seen a lot of people use "HTML5" as a buzzword or umbrella term to refer to the latest web technologies, including WebGL.  In particular, you can't always describe an app as being a "WebGL app" because it almost always relies on newer aspects of HTML 5, CSS, JavaScript, etc., to make it work.  I've often heard these referred to as "HTML5 apps" even if that's not strictly the definition.  It's more modern than saying "Web 2.0" I suppose.